# Sporadic Capybara::Driver::Webkit::WebkitInvalidResponseError:Unable to load URL:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara-webkit

I've got a test which sporadically throws a `Capybara::Driver::Webkit::WebkitInvalidResponseError:Unable to load URL:` error.

Sometimes the test passes just fine and I will rerun the test and it will fail.

I've tried pausing my rspec run, opening up a test server, and can complete the test manually just fine.

I'm using the webkit driver, mac os x mountain lion, rspec2, rails 3.2.1 and ruby 1.9.2.